# cannot locate dockerfile for older version(tags) of postgres

Tags: docker

I'm trying to download postgres-9.6.1 and found that tag in the below page..
Is there a way to get the dockerfile for that tag? I could not see any hyperlink for it.

```
https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres?tab=tags&page=7
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the history of the Dockerfile in the 9.6 directory, which you can find [here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/commits/master/9.6/Dockerfile)

It looks like there are two candidates for 9.6.1:

- [9.6.1-1.pgdg90+1](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/e4942cb0f79b61024963dc0ac196375b26fa60dd/9.6/Dockerfile)
- [9.6.1-2.pgdg80+1](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/1c018f151e703e594e85cbb5c1dc7f6c38b7d49f/9.6/Dockerfile)

I'm not sure which is the most recent one, but I would guess the second.